# r find matching file for multiple condition

Tags: r, file, pattern-matching

I have read a few posts here for file matching, but my questions is not exactly the same.

I am trying to find the file matching 3 conditions, and all 3 condition is a value of another 3 variable within loop, so looks like I can not directly put the variable in the pattern statement

Here is the example

```
c1 = "Curr Month"
c2 = "Entity Lst Yr"
c3 = "36008"
file_from = "my_path/"

f = list.files(path = paste0(file_from, "Account/"), pattern = glob2rx(c1*c2*c3))
```

and my error msg is in the pattern statement

> non-numeric argument to binary operator

Any idea is highly appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: There is call to `paste0()` missing. `glob2rx(paste0(c1, "*", c2, "*", c3))` works without error and returns `"^Curr Month.*Entity Lst Yr.*36008$"`.

Comment: thanks for pointing out! this works perfectly and simple enough

Comment: C_Mu, I don't mind losing the checkmark (really!), is there a reason you un-accepted an answer and have not selected another? If you find neither of the answers work for you, then perhaps you can provide some more info on what doesn't work. If you found a better way (not provided), it's also perfectly fine to answer your own question and accept it. Either way, it's generally a "good thing" to have an accepted answer for questions.

Comment: Hey @r2evans, I must misunderstand you, sorry about that. I thought you want me to put Uwe's answer as checkmark, so I uncheck yours and could not find a way to check his. I will check yours again, sorry for the misunderstanding! Thank you again for your help!

Comment: You can check whichever you prefer. Though you can only "accept" one answer, you can "upvote" as many as you want. I was suggesting that even if you choose to accept mine over Uwe's, then I think Uwe's answer was deserving of an upvote. (I'm not trying to tell you what to upvote, but many "newer users" are not completely aware of the accept/upvote/... options.) If Uwe's completely works for you, though, feel free to deselect mine and figure out how to accept Uwe's ... perhaps a page reload or something ... seems odd that you had no ability to accept it ...

Comment: you are right, i can not tell the difference between accept, upvote ... optiona, but i think I just find it out. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uwe's comment might be simplest for you. If it can be in any order, then you need to be a little more creative.

Since I don't have your files or such, I'll create some samples:

```
# filelisting <- list.files(path=...) # no pattern
filelisting <- c(
  "Rob travel v1.2.docx",
  "the v1.2 version of travel for Rob.xlsx",
  "the v1.3 version of travel for Rob.xlsx",
  "the v1.2 version of travel for Carol.xlsx",
  "something else entirely.pptx",
  "C_Mu.R",
  "My travel v1.2.txt"
)
c1 <- "Rob"
c2 <- "travel"
c3 <- "v1.2"
```

If you need all three but allowing for different orders, then

```
grepl(paste(c1,c2,c3,sep=".*"), filelisting)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

fails because it misses the second file.

Here's a thought:

```
sapply(c(c1,c2,c3), grepl, filelisting)
#        Rob travel  v1.2
# [1,]  TRUE   TRUE  TRUE
# [2,]  TRUE   TRUE  TRUE
# [3,]  TRUE   TRUE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE   TRUE  TRUE
# [5,] FALSE  FALSE FALSE
# [6,] FALSE  FALSE FALSE
# [7,] FALSE   TRUE  TRUE
```

From here, you can simply look for rows where all values are true, such as

```
apply(sapply(c(c1,c2,c3), grepl, filelisting), 1, all)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

(using that to index on `filelisting`).

You can generalize this a little if you have many more than three conditions and/or the number of conditions can change.

```
allcs <- c("Rob", "travel", "v1.2", "docx")
apply(sapply(allcs, grepl, filelisting), 1, all)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Within each string you can use real regex-type stuff (which means you need to escape regex language):

```
allcs <- c("Rob", "travel", "v1.2", "xlsx|docx")
apply(sapply(allcs, grepl, filelisting), 1, all)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help! my files name are following the order, so Uwe's answer simple enough, but thanks again, it will help if I need sth not in a order in the future!

Comment: You might upvote his comment to mark it as helpful. I don't think it provide rep-points, but it still makes the comment prominent.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to combine c1-3 into a regular expressions with wildcards in between? Does the below work?

```
reg <- glob2rx(paste(c1,c2,c3,sep="*"))
print(reg)

[1] "^Curr Month.*Entity Lst Yr.*36008$"
```